# Static Library Created With Visual Studio Shows Undefined Reference To Myfunction when used with codeblocks

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, codeblocks

Hi I have created a static library using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and also created a header which contains all the function prototypes for the functions written in that library but when i link and try to compile it with code block it shows Undefined reference to 'MyFunction' but i have included the header containing its prototype and linked the library. why doesn't it work?

code (library) :

```
int add(int x,int y)
{
      return x+y;
}
```

code (header):

```
int add(int,int);
```

all this works under Visual Studio but not under code blocks.. 
Thanks in Advance... Sorry i am new to programming..

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to link a static library that was created by a different compiler?

Comment: but i used a third party library (BASS audio library) and it worked both with Visual Studio and Code Blocks.

Comment: That would have been an import library rather than a static library

Comment: pardon me ... i am a newbie . what is an import library? and do i have to make a static library for every different compiler ?

Comment: An import library is used to link to a dll. The actual code is external. A static library is self-contained, it has the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries generated by Visual Studio often cannot be consumed by MinGW, and vice versa. There are various reasons for this, but the most common is that the static library is linked against the C++ runtime for the compiler that generated the library. And you are trying to link with a compiler that uses a different runtime.

The problem that you report sounds more like one of mis-matching name managling, but even if you solve the name managling you will likely run into other problems.

The obvious solution is to build multiple versions of the static library, one for each compiler that you use.